# Trying to create a random number generator in c++ and getting an error

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++ and currently trying to code a random number generator from scratch. 
However, I'm getting an error under while statement and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I have some experience in python, so maybe I guess I might be creating python like syntax instead of c++ one? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Random {
public:
    double oldRoot;
    double newRoot;
    int iteNum;

    Random(double aOldRoot, double aNewRoot, int aIteNum) {
        oldRoot = aOldRoot;
        newRoot = aNewRoot;
        iteNum = aIteNum;
    }

    int count = 0;

    while (count <= iteNum) {
        double totalRoot;
        totalRoot = oldRoot + newRoot;
        if totalRoot > 1.0{
            oldRoot = newRoot;
            newRoot = totalRoot - 1.0;
        }
        else {
            oldRoot = newRoot;
            newRoot = totalRoot;
        }
        cout << oldRoot << endl;
        cout << newRoot << endl;

        count += 1
    }

};

int main() {

    Random random10(0.1412, 0.2343, 10);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: ***I'm getting an error under while statement and I don't know what I am doing wrong*** The compiler should tell you. What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: Oh, I see. You have the whole while loop outside any function. Where do you expect it to execute?

Comment: Yeah, seems like that was exactly where I made a mistake. Putting the whole while loop inside a void function helped. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your generator code is not inside a method of the class, it is in the class declaration itself, which is a syntax error.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Random {
public:
    double oldRoot;
    double newRoot;
    int iteNum;

    Random(double aOldRoot, double aNewRoot, int aIteNum) {
        oldRoot = aOldRoot;
        newRoot = aNewRoot;
        iteNum = aIteNum;
    }

    void generate() {
        int count = 0;

        while (count <= iteNum) {
            double totalRoot = oldRoot + newRoot;
            if (totalRoot > 1.0) {
                oldRoot = newRoot;
                newRoot = totalRoot - 1.0;
            }
            else {
                oldRoot = newRoot;
                newRoot = totalRoot;
            }
            cout << oldRoot << endl;
            cout << newRoot << endl;

            count += 1;
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    Random random10(0.1412, 0.2343, 10);
    random10.generate();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ooo! I see you put while loop inside the void function. This actually works now, thank you so much!